# VisualSVN mac checkout error "nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Tags: macos, svn, visualsvn-server

I made a repository by VisualSVN in Windows Server 2012 R2.

After made the repository, I checkout the repository on Windows using TortoiseSVN and it worked.

However, when I checkout Mac mini device, an error occured.

```
svn checkout https://win-h3asdfasdf/svn/asdfasdf --username asdfasdf --password asdfasdf
svn: E170013: Unable to connecto to a repository at URL 'https://win-h3asdfasdf/svn/asdfasdf'
svn: E670008: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Please let me know how can I fix it.

Comment: What svn client version do you use on Mac? Check this with `svn --version`. Most likely it is very outdated and you will not receive this error with the latest versions.

Comment: svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)
   compiled Jun 4 2018, 17:48:35 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Guess, you already don't need an answer, but I faced the same error and got the solution. So I'll share it anyway:
The error says that the URL is wrong, and you probably get this link when you click on the "Checkout" button, so to avoid this error you should write the full name of the address like you get this link when you click on the button:

```
https://win-h3asdfasdf/svn/asdfasdf
```

, then you should add to it its full name:

```
https://win-h3asdfasdf.organization.com/svn/asdfasdf
```